# unknown directive "stream" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:86

Tags: nginx, stream

I have `nginx/1.12.0` and as per document it contains `stream` module. I have installed nginx with the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.0
```

I tried to add stream directive in `nginx.conf`:

```
stream {
    upstream sys {
        server 172.x.x.x:9516;
        server 172.x.x.x:9516;
    }
    server {
        listen 9516 udp;
        proxy_pass sys;
    }
}
```

but when I restart `nginx` I am getting below error in the `nginx` logs

```
unknown directive "stream" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:86

nginx -V output
```

```
nginx version: nginx/1.12.0
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp                                                                                          -buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --w                                                                                          ith-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC'                                                                                           --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/                                                                                          var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path                                                                                          =/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/                                                                                          modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-p                                                                                          ath=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-                                                                                          scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi                                                                                           --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_m                                                                                          odule --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2                                                                                          _module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-                                                                                          http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_modul                                                                                          e --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --wit                                                                                          h-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with                                                                                          -stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with                                                                                          -mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-ZgS12K/nginx-1.12.0/debian/                                                                                          modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-ZgS12K/nginx-1.12.0/d                                                                                          ebian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-ZgS12K/ng                                                                                          inx-1.12.0/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-ZgS12K/                                                                                          nginx-1.12.0/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/ng                                                                                          inx-ZgS12K/nginx-1.12.0/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

I googled this error and some folks say I have to install/configure this module separately. Some says it comes with `nginx` 1.12.0 release. Can someone suggest how I can install/configure this module on already installed `nginx`?

Regards
VG

Comment: Is Nginx starting with the stream module enabled? Please post the output of `nginx -V`.

Comment: Thanks Joe, So I have updated my question and paste my nginx -V output .

Comment: Under /usr/lib/nginx/modules I can see following modules ngx_http_image_filter_module.so
ngx_http_geoip_module.so
ngx_http_echo_module.so
ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so
ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so
ngx_stream_module.so
ngx_mail_module.so
ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so
ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so
ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The stream module is being added as dynamic, as per:

```
--with-stream=dynamic
```

You need it to be 'static' - so load the module directly. To do so, add the following at the very top of your nginx.conf:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;
```

Then:

```
nginx -t
```

If all is well:

```
nginx -s reload
service nginx restart
```

Edit:

```
-s signal' Send signal to the master process. The argument signal can be one of: stop, quit, reopen, reload. The following table shows the corresponding system signals.

stop' SIGTERM
quit' SIGQUIT
reopen' SIGUSR1
reload' SIGHUP
```

Comment: Awesome!! no more errors . Thanks alot Joe you are my savior .BTW what is nginx -s actually while running this I am getting below error nginx: option "-s" requires parameter

Comment: I edited my answer, I missed a bit. nginx -s reload reloads the master process - the service restart basically does the same thing.

Comment: what is `stream` module going to do? what is the use of it

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Is there any way to automate this process bcoz EC2 instance will not be permanent for EBS, also if you could can you explain why Steam Module needs to be static to work

Comment: What does nginx -t do?

Comment: `load_module /usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so; ` is needed in some cases. (64bit systems)

Comment: Excellent this worked for me on ubuntu 20.04 in azure

Answer (score 19):

I have come across this issue with `nginx` on Amazon Linux running on AWS EC2 instance, and my `/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/` folder was empty.

I installed the module with `yum`:

```
yum install nginx-mod-stream
```

The `stream` directive works now without changing the `nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 10):

Have not enough reputation to comment Joe's answer, so writing here:

On CentOS7, the modules path located under lib64 folder. So, you need to add this line:

```
load_module '/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so';
```

Comment: is correct. in centos 7.9, you only need to "yum install nginx-mod-stream". then nginx -t, it is up.